# BD-RE eject only with disc on it

Tags: drivers, dvd, desktop-computer, blu-ray, cd

My BD-RE Drive on pc eject normally only if it have disc on it

If there no disc i eject it only by using needle on the hole

Why?
I opened it and clean it but didn't fix

Comment: Did you try pushing the button multiple times? I have a similar problem and my drive is jammed all the time.

Comment: Yeah I pushing it but didn't eject - if it have disc one click enough to eject